# Can I create a bootable USB drive for BOTH Windows 10 and Linux?

Tags: boot, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive

I am seeking to **create a bootable USB drive which will allow me to boot into either Windows 10 or Linux, as needed**.

I have a 512Gb WD MyPassport SSD and a MacBook Pro. I currently have my 128Gb internal SSD partitioned so I can boot into either MacOS or Windows 10 (with BootCamp). 128Gb is not really enough for *two* operating systems, much less three (or four, since I would actually like access to two different Linux distros), so I need to figure something else out.

What I am looking for is **a method to turn my WD SSD into a bootable drive from which I can boot into Windows 10, or one or another Linux distro**. Further, I would like to simply move my current Windows 10 to the WD SSD (although, if I have to buy a new version, so be it).

If this is simply a matter of creating 3 partitions on the drive, then making each one a bootable external drive, I can probably do that. However, I am worried that it is going to be more complicated than that. Let me know what you think! <3

Comment: IIRC windows 7 won't install on USB drives. I don't know about 10 though.

Answer (score 0):

This should be roughly as simple as making a drive with 3 partitions in EFI Partition Map mode, yes.

The first partition should be your EFI System partition, at least 512MB in size (that size is required for certain linux distros) and formatted as FAT32. You shouldn't need to put anything special on this partition.

The remaining partitions should be bootable versions of whatever OS you like, formatted correctly with their particular filesystem.

Let me know how this works out!

Comment: I'd suggest installing Windows first, then Linux. Most linux installers allow for easy setup alongside Windows. They do the partitioning for you and will install GRUB in the MBR so you can easily choose what you want to boot on startup.

Comment: @confetti it is a Mac, So UEFI. No MBR.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine in principle, so long as you are not planning the OSs to be bootable on other machines (Windows is extremely machine-dependent). You can just set them up as if the external drive is an internal drive.

Personally I would also keep the bootloader on your main drive, rather than trying to make the external drive bootloader the primary one when it is present... So the external drive would only have individual partitions for the OSs, not a boot partition of any sort.

Note that three-way booting on a Mac is not as straightforward as using Windows and Boot Camp. It requires the use of a third-party bootloader: you can't simply use Grub or Boot Camp for it. A guide like [this one](https://robpickering.com/triple-boot-macbook-pro-macos-windows-10-linux/) can help you with that.